# Calculating the silhouette coefficient in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I run a code taken from this website for calculating Silhouette Coefficient, but the code is running with error

Here is the code

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import *
iris = datasets.load_iris()
col = iris.feature_names
name = iris.target_names
X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = col)
y = iris.target
s = silhouette_score(X.values, y, metric='euclidean',sample_size=50)
```

The error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2e1432d3b9ce> in <module>
      4 col = iris.feature_names
      5 name = iris.target_names
----> 6 X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = col)
      7 y = iris.target
      8 s = silhouette_score(X.values, y, metric='euclidean',sample_size=50)

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you googled the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import pandas first

```
import pandas as pd
```

If you don't have it installed you'll need to install pandas first. Run this in the command line

```
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score -1):

The `pandas` library is generally imported as `pd`.

Install it (if you don't have it already), then add

```
import pandas as pd
```

and you're off to the races.